# MLE estimation with serially correlated errors

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, statistics, applied-econometrics

I want to estimate the parameters of $a_t = a_{t-1}+\theta+\epsilon_t$ using MLE. Assume errors $\epsilon_t$ are serially correlated, then how would I choose the likelihood function?

Comment: Do you know anything about how they are serially correlated?

Comment: No, but let's assume a first order serial correlation $\epsilon_t = \rho\epsilon_{t-1}+e_t$

Comment: What paramters are you estimating? Presumably the coefficeint on the lagged value..

Comment: yes, it is the parameter on $da_t$

Answer (score -2):

This is model is known an GARCH(general autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity) where the AR component of the observable series $\{a_t\}$ is equal to unity.

The likelihood is determined by your model assumptions on the innovation terms $\varepsilon_t$ and $e_t$.

If you are looking for a canned function to estimate an GARCH see https://www.kevinsheppard.com/MFE_Toolbox. If you are looking for some more theory on how to form the likelihood see http://www.math.elte.hu/probability/markus/AlkmatTS1/ARCH_GARCH_Eload.html.

Comment: This is not an ARCH model.

Comment: Updated to reflect that it is really GARCH. My mistake.